# Does PMD tool have an option to display the difference in violations count (before and after code change)?

Tags: java, pmd

I am trying to generate report using PMD command line tool. My aim is to find out the difference in the violations count after I have changed the code. The intention is to highlight if any new violations have occurred after the previous run of pmd tool.

This is the command I have used for running the pmd tool. It is able to generate report in html format.

```
./pmd.bat -dir "C:\Source_code_folder\" -cache "C:\temp\temp.txt" -f html -R "C:\Source_code_folder\rules.xml" > C:\temp\temp.html
```

The expectation is to print delta violations count on screen. One of the ways which I thought was to extract info from the report manually(using script), sum it and echo the result. I'm not aware of any option inbuilt in pmd which does the same.

Comment: There are no such built-in options in PMD

Comment: git commit hooks - doesn't it avoid new violations which can eliminate the need for this in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality in PMD at the moment.
There is, however, an issue raised where you might wish to add your input.

https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/2116